# Multiple CSVs to import into R with missing key data

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to clean a data set in R. The data is in multiple CSV files. My problem comes in where there is missing data. I would like to merge all of the close prices for multiple currency pairs into a data frame. I haven't been able find a way to merge these prices to the associated dates, because there are missing dates (actually minutes). So for example, The first CSV has dates 1, 2, 3, 4 with the associated prices. CSV 2 has dates 1, 3, 4 with the associated prices. I am thinking I just want to drop the dates from the CSV, just not sure how to do this.

```
    CSV 1                 CSV 2
Date    USD/EUR       Date      JPY/USD
1       1.00           1         2.00
2       1.01           3         3.10 
3       1.03           4         2.00
4       1.01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 'Date' is unique, you can use `merge` for a `base` solution

```
csv1 <- read.csv("csv1.csv", header=T)
csv2 <- read.csv("csv2.csv", header=T)

merge(csv2, csv1, by="Date", all.y=TRUE)

  Date JPY/USD USD.EUR
1    1     2.0    1.00
2    2      NA    1.01
3    3     3.1    1.03
4    4     2.0    1.01
```

There is also the `join` function in the `plyr` package.  Please note, however, that the resulting dataframe is not ordered by Date.

```
join(csv2, csv1, by="Date", type="full")

  Date JPY/USD USD.EUR
1    1     2.0    1.00
2    3     3.1    1.03
3    4     2.0    1.01
4    2      NA    1.01
```

Alternately, if you want to begin exploring the valuable `data.table` package, you can do the same thing quite easily.

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(csv1, key="Date")
dt2 <- data.table(csv2, key="Date")
dt3 <- dt2[dt1, ]
dt3

   Date JPY/USD USD.EUR
1:    1     2.0    1.00
2:    2      NA    1.01
3:    3     3.1    1.03
4:    4     2.0    1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `dplyr` rather than `plyr`. The dev version (dplyr 0.4) has `full_join`.

```
csv1 <- data.frame(Date = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   USDEUR = c(1, 1.01, 1.03, 1.01))

csv2 <- data.frame(Date = c(1, 3, 4),
                   JPYEUR = c(2, 3.1, 2))

full_join(csv1, csv2, by = "Date")

#  Date USDEUR JPYEUR
#1    1   1.00    2.0
#2    2   1.01     NA
#3    3   1.03    3.1
#4    4   1.01    2.0
```

**EXTRA**

I just checked how much time each option would take. This is not a proper benchmark, but this will give you an idea.

```
set.seed(123)
csv1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = 1, to = 1000000, by = 1),
                   USDEUR = runif(1000000, 1, 1.50))

csv2 <- data.frame(Date = sample.int(c(1, 1000000),950000, replace = TRUE),
                   JPYEUR = runif(950000, 2, 3.2))


system.time(merge(csv2, csv1, by = "Date", all.y = TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 11.395   0.272  11.590 

system.time(join(csv2, csv1, by = "Date", type = "full"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.510   0.282   3.713

system.time(full_join(csv1, csv2, by = "Date"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.863   0.040   0.894 

dt1 <- setDT(csv1)
dt2 <- setDT(csv2)

setkey(dt1, "Date")
setkey(dt2, "Date")

system.time(dt2[dt1, ])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.072   0.008   0.079
```